# Regex with prefix condition

Tags: regex

I am looking for help in constructing the regex that matches both `/static/abc-123/` and `static/xyz-abc/pqr`. Basically, anything following `/static` (including just `/static`). Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know. For what it's worth, I gave you +1 (some time ago) to compensate a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the start-of-string anchor `^`:

```
^/static
```

Assuming forward slash delimiters, as is fairly common:

```
/^\/static/
```

Of course, if you aren't restricted to regex, I would suggest using string prefix (or "startsWith" or similar) methods instead!

Comment: Nice answer covering all the bases. +1 :)